# how to get end time after dropping event in calender automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  defaultView:'agendaDay',
  unselectAuto: false,
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: false,
  editable: true,
  droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
  drop: function() { },
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.find(".fc-content").append("<span class='close' data-id='" + event._id +"'>x</span>");
                },
                eventResize:function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
                console.log("event",event);
                alert("StartTime : "+new Date(event.start));
                eve = "Channel name : "+ event.title;
                s = "StartTime : "+new Date(event.start);
                ee = " End "+new Date(event.end);
                alert(eve+"\n"+s+"\n"+ee);
                <!--alert("Event : "+ event.title+" StartTime : "+new Date(event.start)+" End "+new Date(event.end));-->
                },
                });
                });

// remove event on click in calender
    $(document).on('click', '.close', function(){
    debugger;
    var id = $(this).data('id'); 
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', id); 
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

    $("#btnReset").click(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
});
```

i want to display end time after dropping event into calender
and how to get complete calender event details (i.e.) event name and start & end time of each events in a single alert box?

[Complete source code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AsifAadeez/h0emqa6c/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see fullCalendar event object [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) where is list of properties related to event

for drop event you can use:

```
eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta) {
            alert(event.end + ' formated date: ' +$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));


}
```

and via alert display any event property.